# Is it possible for a scrollpane to have multiple tabs in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, jtabbedpane

So I think I need to split my scroll pane list because it's over 100 items I want to display. I was thinking I could have a scroll pane with tabs with each of the tabs having different parts of the list. Kind of like a tabbed pane, but just for the scroll pane like it's just one component. The problem is I don't know how to do this or if it is possible.

Comment: *"I think I need to split my scroll pane list because it's over 100 items I want to display."* What is the type of information in this list? What is the logical basis of the divisions between the various 'parts' of the information? Species? Date? Team? .. I need this information in order to have any chance of determining how to best present the data to the user of the app. **BTW:** '100' does not seem to be very many. But 100 of what?

Comment: Normally, managing large amounts of data is accomplished is with a user filter.  Add a JTextField to your window, and whenever the user types in it, use the text as a search term and only show the list items which contain that term.  (Ideally, you should use a non-repeating javax.swing.Timer to start the search, which is restarted each time the text changes, so the search starts about a second after the typing stops and thus typing several characters quickly doesn’t initiate several searches only to discard most of them.)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson It's a list  of instruments that can be played using MIDI. I thought 100 would be too much and thought I could split the instruments up by their instruments families.

Comment: @VGR I was thinking of having something like that user filter, but I'm not sure every user would know all the different options.

Comment: You can of course add more controls than a single text field.  What are some of the options you’re considering?

Comment: @VGR *"You can .. add more controls than a single text field."* Perhaps a `JComboBox` of common options, editable for searching specific strings in a `JTable`. A sound bank might also lend itself to a `JTree` with branches of types and leaves of instruments, with selections shown in a details panel..

Comment: @VGR I'll just clear up the fact that by options I mean all the instruments. I just felt I was making it more confusing. About the different options for controls, originally I had thought about having checkboxes and radio buttons. I'm still new to working on my own projects so I wasn't sure what would work. Later, I thought that a scroll pane and radio buttons could be something I could try. I would have the user select items from the scroll pane list and then have some radio buttons become visible or not grayed out based on those items.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I thought about using a JTree, I'm just not very sure how it would look or work. I never used stuff like user filter or JTree. JTable I might have dealt with before, but I don't remember. Combo box might work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: A lot of the 'devil in the detail' lies in how exactly the code would divide the instruments into groups. Do you define a 'Stringed Instrument' category with sub-categories 'Plucked', 'Bowed' & 'Struck'? Of course this requires the program to know in which category to put each instrument..

Comment: I was planning on dividing the instruments the way they are grouped up like in the first table on this website [here](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/gm-level-1-sound-set)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which displays the MIDI instruments for all banks in a `JTable`. Above it offers three combo boxes (`JComboBox`) and a `JTextField`.

The text field can search (case insensitive) for any string the user enters.

The combos can be used to filter for:

1. Categories of instruments.
2. Types of instruments.
3. Common strings in instrument names.

[image]

Oh, and I threw in a `JList` of the categories. It does nothing, but if I was doing this over, I'd start with, and only have, the list in the `LINE_START` position.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MidiInstrumentSearch {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    Instrument[] instruments;
    JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel("Message Label");
    JTable table;
    MidiInstrumentTableModel tm;
    TableRowSorter sorter;
    InstrumentCategory[] instrumentCategories = {
        new InstrumentCategory("All", 1, 10000),
        new InstrumentCategory("Piano", 1, 8),
        new InstrumentCategory("Chromatic Percussion", 9, 16),
        new InstrumentCategory("Organ", 17, 24),
        new InstrumentCategory("Guitar", 25, 32),
        new InstrumentCategory("Bass", 33, 40),
        new InstrumentCategory("Strings", 41, 48),
        new InstrumentCategory("Ensemble", 49, 56),
        new InstrumentCategory("Brass", 57, 64),
        new InstrumentCategory("Reed", 65, 72),
        new InstrumentCategory("Pipe", 73, 80),
        new InstrumentCategory("Synth Lead", 81, 88),
        new InstrumentCategory("Synth Pad", 89, 96),
        new InstrumentCategory("Synth Effects", 97, 104),
        new InstrumentCategory("Ethnic", 105, 112),
        new InstrumentCategory("Percussive", 113, 120),
        new InstrumentCategory("Sound Effects", 121, 128)
    };

    MidiInstrumentSearch() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void initUI() throws MidiUnavailableException {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }
        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        ui.add(messageLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(new JList(instrumentCategories)), 
                BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synthesizer.open();
        instruments = synthesizer.getAvailableInstruments();
        InstrumentPOJO[] inst = new InstrumentPOJO[instruments.length];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < inst.length; ii++) {
            inst[ii] = new InstrumentPOJO(instruments[ii]);
        }
        tm = new MidiInstrumentTableModel(inst);
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tm);
        table = new JTable(tm);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ui.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        final JComboBox categoryBox = new JComboBox<>(instrumentCategories);
        ActionListener categoryListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            InstrumentCategory ic = (InstrumentCategory) categoryBox.getSelectedItem();
            CategoryFilter categoryFilter = new CategoryFilter(ic);
            sorter.setRowFilter(categoryFilter);
            setNumber();
        };
        categoryBox.addActionListener(categoryListener);
        toolBar.add(new JLabel("Category"));
        toolBar.add(categoryBox);

        toolBar.add(new JLabel("Type"));
        String[] types = {"", "Instrument", "Drumkit"};
        final JComboBox typeBox = new JComboBox<>(types);
        toolBar.add(typeBox);
        ActionListener typeSearchListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            String s = typeBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter(0, s);
            sorter.setRowFilter(sf);
            setNumber();
        };
        typeBox.addActionListener(typeSearchListener);

        String[] nameCommon = {
            "", "bass", "bell", "brass", "bs",
            "drum", "flute", "gt", "harp", "horn",
            "org", "orch", "pad", "piano",
            "sax", "str", "syn", "vox", "wave"
        };
        final JComboBox nameBox = new JComboBox(nameCommon);
        ActionListener nameListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter(1, nameBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            sorter.setRowFilter(sf);
            setNumber();
        };
        nameBox.addActionListener(nameListener);
        toolBar.add(new JLabel("Name"));
        toolBar.add(nameBox);

        JTextField searchField = new JTextField("Enter to Search", 12);
        toolBar.add(searchField);
        ActionListener textSearchListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter(1, e.getActionCommand());
            sorter.setRowFilter(sf);
            setNumber();
        };
        searchField.addActionListener(textSearchListener);
    }

    private void setNumber() {
        int i = table.getRowCount();
        setNumber(i);
    }

    private void setNumber(int n) {
        messageLabel.setText(n + " presets");
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            MidiInstrumentSearch o = new MidiInstrumentSearch();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class InstrumentPOJO {

    private final Instrument instrument;
    private final String category;
    private final String name;
    private final int bank;
    private final int preset;

    InstrumentPOJO(Instrument instrument) {
        this.instrument = instrument;
        String s = instrument.toString();
        category = getTextBetween(s, "", ":");
        name = getTextBetween(s, ":", "bank");
        bank = Integer.parseInt(getTextBetween(s, "bank #", " preset"));
        String pre = "preset #";
        int index = s.indexOf(pre);
        s = s.substring(index + pre.length());
        preset = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

    private String getTextBetween(String s, String s1, String s2) {
        int i1 = s.indexOf(s1);
        int c1 = i1 + s1.length();
        int i2 = s.indexOf(s2);
        return s.substring(c1, i2).trim();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getCategory() + " \t"
                + getName() + " \t"
                + getBank() + " \t"
                + getPreset() + " \t";
    }

    public Instrument getInstrument() {
        return instrument;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    public int getPreset() {
        return preset;
    }
}

class MidiInstrumentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    final static String[] colNames = {"Category", "Name", "Bank", "Preset"};
    InstrumentPOJO[] orchestra;

    MidiInstrumentTableModel(InstrumentPOJO[] orchestra) {
        this.orchestra = orchestra;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return orchestra.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        final InstrumentPOJO ip = orchestra[rowIndex];
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return ip.getCategory();
            case 1:
                return ip.getName();
            case 2:
                return ip.getBank();
            case 3:
                return ip.getPreset();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return colNames[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return String.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            case 2:
                return Integer.class;
            case 3:
                return Integer.class;
            default:
                return Integer.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }
}

class SearchFilter extends RowFilter {

    int col;
    String target;

    SearchFilter(int col, String target) {
        this.col = col;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean include(Entry entry) {
        String s = entry.getValue(col).toString();
        return s.toLowerCase().contains(target.toLowerCase());
    }
}

class CategoryFilter extends RowFilter {

    InstrumentCategory cat;

    CategoryFilter(InstrumentCategory cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean include(Entry entry) {
        int i = (Integer) entry.getValue(3) + 1;
        return (i >= cat.getFirst() && i <= cat.getLast());
    }
}

class InstrumentCategory {

    private final String name;
    private final int first;
    private final int last;

    public InstrumentCategory(String name, int first, int last) {
        this.name = name;
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the first
     */
    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    /**
     * @return the last
     */
    public int getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great example of having a table with the list of instruments. It seems to me like I was imagining things thinking that I saw a scrollpane with tabs when I first asked my question. I feel as though I would need a different approach than a table for what I'm doing. If I can click to highlight a selection and can trigger an event through that selection then I could find a way to do it this way. Then again it might be too much space taken up by the table. I'm not sure.

Comment: There are likely ways to fix each of your concerns. Since it's obvious you have not decided what this GUI should look like or how it should work, I'm not spending more time on it. Come up with those details, and I *might* revisit it. As to how it will look.. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: I'll just keep working on the GUI for this program and go from there. If I feel the need for a second opinion, I will come back to this post or create a new one. I'll provide a drawing/diagram then.